# Laravel Voyager v1.1 date format not working

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

I tried to make the date field with different format on Laravel Voyager 1.1 as shown below:

[image: bread date field format]

and yet the upon creation of the record its still using the default format:

[image: date format still not affected]

Answer (score 3):

the correct syntax is

{
    "format" : "%d-%m-%Y"
}

Answer (score 0):

When you change the formate, it will only change in view blade (`/vendor/tcg/voyager/resources/views/bread/read.blade.php`) not in `edit/add` view.

If you want to change it in `add/edit` view as well, you need to overwrite the default blade of voyager. You need to overwrite/alter following blade file as per your requirement:

```
/vendor/tcg/voyager/resources/views/formfields/date.blade.php
```

Comment: <input type="date" class="form-control" name="{{ $row->field }}"
       placeholder="{{ $row->display_name }}"
       value="@if(isset($dataTypeContent->{$row->field})){{ gmdate('d-m-Y', strtotime(old($row->field, $dataTypeContent->{$row->field}))) }}@else{{old($row->field)}}@endif">

Comment: I change the format on the date.blade.php as shown above the the 'd-m-Y' fromat still on the edit not giving me any changes

Answer (score 0):

Still facing this issue in 2023, this is how I solved:

1- On my rewrite template resources/views/vendor/voyager/formfields/timestamp.blade.php I've changed the class of the input to:

class="form-control custom-datepicker"

2- Added custom js as explained here: https://voyager-docs.devdojo.com/customization/additional-css-js with:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.custom-datepicker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm'
    });
})
```